# DRF simplejwt do not updating the access token

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm using **simpleJWT** with **Django restframework** and i get this problem when i tried to refresh the access token, i post http request sending the refresh token to the refresh endpoint, it suppose to get new access, **but i keep getting the same access token even though the access token has expired !**

- what's reason that might cause this ?
- is there anyone can help please ?

***setting.py***

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer'),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('api/', include('api.urls')),

    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

***views.py***

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

from .models import Project, Message
from .serializers import ProjectSerializer, MessageSerializer,CustomUserSerializer




class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ProjectList (generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

class ProjectDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

class MessageList (generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

class MessageDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

***rest_framework_simplejwt.views.py***

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from . import serializers
from .authentication import AUTH_HEADER_TYPES
from .exceptions import InvalidToken, TokenError
from .settings import api_settings


class TokenViewBase(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    serializer_class = None
    _serializer_class = ""

    www_authenticate_realm = "api"

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """
        If serializer_class is set, use it directly. Otherwise get the class from settings.
        """

        if self.serializer_class:
            return self.serializer_class
        try:
            return import_string(self._serializer_class)
        except ImportError:
            msg = "Could not import serializer '%s'" % self._serializer_class
            raise ImportError(msg)

    def get_authenticate_header(self, request):
        return '{} realm="{}"'.format(
            AUTH_HEADER_TYPES[0],
            self.www_authenticate_realm,
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class TokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a set of user credentials and returns an access and refresh JSON web
    token pair to prove the authentication of those credentials.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER


token_obtain_pair = TokenObtainPairView.as_view()


class TokenRefreshView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a refresh type JSON web token and returns an access type JSON web
    token if the refresh token is valid.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER


token_refresh = TokenRefreshView.as_view()


class TokenObtainSlidingView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a set of user credentials and returns a sliding JSON web token to
    prove the authentication of those credentials.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER


token_obtain_sliding = TokenObtainSlidingView.as_view()


class TokenRefreshSlidingView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a sliding JSON web token and returns a new, refreshed version if the
    token's refresh period has not expired.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER


token_refresh_sliding = TokenRefreshSlidingView.as_view()


class TokenVerifyView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a token and indicates if it is valid.  This view provides no
    information about a token's fitness for a particular use.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER


token_verify = TokenVerifyView.as_view()


class TokenBlacklistView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a token and blacklists it. Must be used with the
    `rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist` app installed.
    """

    _serializer_class = api_settings.TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER


token_blacklist = TokenBlacklistView.as_view()
```

Comment: Can you add your views to the question please

Comment: thank you sir for responding, for sure i added it above , but i'didn't overide any view ,i'm just using views come up with SimpleJWT package

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the token to the blacklist after you rotate with the refresh token:

```
 'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
```

Like this the access token will be sent to the blacklist and will no longer be called. Where you will receive a new one to have access.